# Recruiting races in FFT A2

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-a2

In Final Fantasy Tactics A2: Grimoire of the Rift, I've recruited humes, bangaas, Nu Mous, Seeqs, and a Gria, but I've yet to get the chance to recruit a moogle or a viera. Is there a prerequisite condition to be able to recruit these two races?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Moogles, there is no requisite other than being in the right places (Goug and Bisga Greenlands, if I recall correctly) at the right months (Goldsun and Silversun).

For Viera, you need to have completed the Moon Seal quest first (comes after the Star Seal quest). Then they'll have the same essence of being at the right places in the right months.

Just to be complete, Gria are the only race besides Viera who have a prerequisite. You must have access to Fluorgis first before they can be recruited, even though they also can be found in Zedlei Forest.

Comment: @Grace-Note Thanks for the quick answer. Out of curiosity, do Seeqs have a prerequisite, or are they restricted solely because of their class prerequisites?

Comment: @Arkive No pre-reqs for Seeq, Hume, Bangaa, Nu Mou, or Moogle. Only Viera and Gria.

Comment: also, you can recruit the races via the recruitment quest (appears after the first auction) once they have been unlocked during the month they are supposed to spawn.  The class you can choose from those quests are also predetermined (only unlocked ones can be obtained, however), which allows you to have a better chance of getting what you want.